# Java Threads When Using Replicate Runs

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a really odd bug with some Java code I'm writing. If I run some parallel code I've written it runs perfectly, however if I run the same code multiple times in the same run the runtime gets slower and slower each time.

If I increase the number threads from 4 to 8, the slowdown is more dramatic each iteration.

Each run is completely independent, I even set the runtime variable to null in between to clear the old run. So I have no idea what could be slowing it down. I've been using the Visual VM and it says that .run() is spending all of its time on "Self Time" or "Thread.init()" which is not helpful.

Some snippets of code:

```
for (int r = 0; r < replicateRuns; ++r) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    result = newRuntime.execute();
    result = null;
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
    total += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

---

```
    parentThread = this;
    thread = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
    barrier = new CyclicBarrier(numberOfThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        thread[i] = new Thread(new Runtime(parentThread, variation, delta, eta, i,
                numberOfThreads), i + "");
        thread[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        try {
            thread[i].join();
            thread[i] = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So any clues at to why if I launch the Java app many times I get decent results, but if I run it many times within the same launch everything slows down, even though as far as I can see I'm null'ing everything so the GC comes and cleans it.

I'm using thread local variables, but from what I've read they're all cleaned when the thread itself is set to null.

Cheers for any help!

EDIT 1:

Thanks for all the help. The plot thickens, on my Windows desktop (as opposed to my MacBook) there are no issues at all, each thread runs fine with no slow down inbetween even when I increase the amount of runs! After staring at this for a day I'm going to try again with Eclipse MAT first thing in the morning.

With regards to the source, I'm extending the MOEA framework with a parallel version of MOEAD, hence the many dependencies and classes. [MOEA framework](http://www.moeaframework.org/) You can find the source of my class [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8k3k9oerpq4m75/ParallelMOEAD.java) . Essentially iterate is called repeatedly until numberOfEvaulations reaches a set figure.

Comment: To get better help sooner, you should try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). That way, people will be able to test your code, reproduce the issue and possibly find the problem. For example, without knowing what `new Runtime(...)` is, it is difficult to reason about your problem.

Comment: I'll try and post more code, but there's a massive class hiearchy and I don't want to spam people with a wall of code. It was more of a general "do I need to do more than null a thread" to clear it question.

Comment: The idea is to extract from your code a minimal compilable example that reproduces the behaviour. Nulling the thread does not do much - if the thread is still running it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: "Setting thread to null" is a meaningless statement. A thread is either alive or dead.

Comment: You didn't post any relevant code. The slowdown occurs within your Runtime code. I could give you general advice: don't use thread locals, have the Runtime object hold all state.

Comment: I've added a link to the full source of the Java class for people that are asking. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It seems that there are no ThreadLocal variables in the code. The OP was possibly referring to variables which are confined to a thread.

Comment: @user1768430 You could maybe add some sort of logging (could be a print statement) at the end of your `run` method to make sure it does exit properly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem as guys are saying here is that you are not 'stopping' your threads in the right way - sort of speak.

The best way in my experience is to store a state in a thread, in a boolean variable e.g. `isRunning`. Then inside your loop you test the state of the `isRunning` flag, i.e.

```
//inside the run method
while(isRunning){
//your code goes here
}
```

This way on each iteration of the loop you are checking the current state of the flag thus when you will set it to 'false' in, for example, your custom `stop()` method. The next iteration of the loop will cause the thread to exit its `run` method thus ending life of your thread. Well technically now it becomes ready to be garbage collected. It's memory will be deallocated at some point in the near future, considering there is no reference to this threat hanging in some place in your code.

There is more sources showing this approach, for example, check out [this discussion on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Killing-threads-in-java-program-70526.S.191670441?view=&srchtype=discussedNews&gid=70526&item=191670441&type=member&trk=eml-anet_dig-b_pd-ttl-hdp&ut=0AA26BiLWSO5w1).

*As a side note it would be actually useful to see what exactly is the `newRuntime` or `result` variables, their classes and inheritance etc. Otherwise we can only try to guess as to what actually is going on in your code.*

Comment: As Boro said, it's not good to kill the thread, or loose the reference, this is not ok, because if the thread is alive, it wont stop, even if you don't keep the reference. Just let it finish the execution, and it will die naturally =). On the other hand, your performance issue could be if you have some synchronized resources being used in the execution, so each thread could be waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are always generating new threads and never disposing of them .
If the number of threads is larger than the number of processor cores we have to switch threads , which can decrease performance about 1000 times .
If you are using Netbeans IDE , in profiler you can the threads and their status .